# Guest VM not able to access internet and routerGW via br0 in Centos7 KVM environment

Tags: centos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kvm

I have setup KVM environment over VirtualBox (nested Vt).
The guest VM Ubuntu can ping VM host Centos7 and vise-versa but not able to access internet and not able to ping my InternetLANrouter gw (192.168.0.1). I have create bridge br0 and mapping with interface enp0s3. VMHostCentos7 able to ping my LAN, routerGW and able to access internet.
I created VMGuestUbuntu16 and use br0 network. VMGuestUbuntu16 able to get dhcp ip (192.168.0.145) and able to ping VMHostCentos7 but not able to ping routerGW 192.168.0.1 and cannot access internet.
I have also turn off NetworkManager and add ipforwarding 'net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1'
Please advise what could be wrong here and maybe I miss some of the configuration. Please help. Thank you.

The setup as follow:-

```
PhysicalHost [virtualbox]---VMHostCentos7---KVM---VMGuestUbuntu16
IP:192.168.0.141            192.168.0.110          192.168.0.145

**VMHostCentos7**

**(1)IFCONFIG**
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2001:e68:5435:ccce:a00:27ff:fe47:8412  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe47:8412  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:47:84:12  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 54148  bytes 3915355 (3.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 77447  bytes 56912501 (54.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe47:8412  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:47:84:12  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 53931  bytes 4689769 (4.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 89777  bytes 73006443 (69.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 62865  bytes 847930152 (808.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62865  bytes 847930152 (808.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:62:dc:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

**(2) IP A**
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:47:84:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe47:8412/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a4:15:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:47:84:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.110/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 603473sec preferred_lft 603473sec
    inet6 2001:e68:5435:ccce:a00:27ff:fe47:8412/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86395sec preferred_lft 86395sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe47:8412/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:62:dc:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:62:dc:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:a2:b5:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fea2:b56d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

**(3)bridge link show br0**
2: enp0s3 state UP : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 4
6: virbr0-nic state DOWN : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 master virbr0 state disabled priority 32 cost 100
7: vnet0 state UNKNOWN : <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 100

**(4) ip route**
default via 192.168.0.1 dev br0
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0 scope link metric 1004
192.168.0.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.110
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1

**(5) brctl show**
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.080027478412       yes             enp0s3
                                                        vnet0
virbr0          8000.52540062dc29       yes             virbr0-nic

**(6) virsh net-list**
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes



**VMGuestUbuntu16**
(1) virsh edit U1604_BR0
.....
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:a2:b5:6d'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>

    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'>
      <listen type='address'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

*After allow all promiscuous mode on my virtualbox, my vm guest able to ping physical host ip but yet still not able to access internet. Still no able to resolve this problem... I have search but still no solution of my problem. Appreciate for help.*

---

Output below

```
VMCentos (Host)
No Output when VMUbuntu(guess) ping router gw. 
[root@mykvm_01 ~]# tcpdump -i br0 -ne icmp

VMUbuntu (guess)
ping 192.168.0.1 ===> router gw
From 192.168.0.145 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.145 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.145 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable


VMCentos (Host)
[root@mykvm_01 ~]# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
22380 1455K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   31  7284 INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   31  7284 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   31  7284 INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
   27  7012 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 33030 packets, 26M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
   36  4032 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
33030   26M OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   31  7284 IN_public  all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
    0     0 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   31  7284 IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   31  7284 IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   31  7284 IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    2   168 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    2   104 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Updated today 7/8:-
I have created new VM guess and using virbr0 (NAT) and this VM able to ping routergw and able to access internet. This is not the setup I want as I'm not able to access/ssh the guess VM thru my LAN or from other pc. I still need to use bridge br0 interface and resolve why not able to ping gw and access internet. Must be something missing in my setup.. could be firewall?

Comment: `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` should not matter in this case as it is about IP (layer 3) but your connectivity is on layer 2 (bridging the LAN to the inner VM). Add the outputs of `brctl show` and (while you are pinging the router from both VMs) `tcpdump -i br0 -ne icmp and \( host 192.168.0.110 or host 192.168.0.145 \)` and `iptables -nvL` to your question.

Comment: Hi...brctl show output is already shared. Will update the rest soon. Thanks

Comment: Updated above with tcpdump and iptables output. Appreciate for help. Thanks